# Azure Media Services and HTML5 Video

Tags: html, azure, media, azure-media-services

I want to use Azure Media Services to allow my users to upload a video (in any file format -- supported by the media services of course) and then perform the following steps:

- Create MP4, WEBM, and OGV converted endpoints to allow any browser to stream the video
- Create a thumbnail for the video by selected a random frame

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

WEBM and OGV are not supported by Windows Azure Media Encoder. You can find a list a available presets here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129582.aspx

Thumbnails creation is possible.

You will find all you need on this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973629.aspx

Hope this helps !

Julien