# which Azure Media Services V3 transform presets can I use to produce .webm output

Tags: azure, video-processing, azure-media-services

I'm so far unable to identify a [preset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/transforms/update#standardencoderpreset) for an Azure Media Services V3 Transform that will encode a video into `.webm` format.

[This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/custom-preset-rest-howto) explains how to create a custom transform preset, which would be helpful if I could identify the `webm` format [like this one for mp4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/transforms/update#mp4format).

Is it possible that AMS simply doesn't support `webm`?
is this [Azure Media Services and HTML5 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956468/azure-media-services-and-html5-video) really  still the whole story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMS does not currently support WebM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-encoder-standard-formats

I'd be interested in any business justification for the requirement that you may have. We don't get a lot of customers asks for it (surprisingly).

Comment: we do specialized enterprise content management. I am trying to migrate video transcoding from s3 to AMS (which does support `webm`). Since our customers are doing any number of things with the videos, i can't say it's any one requirement beyond not disrupting their existing workflows.

Comment: Thanks @Ben - If you find that there is a specific combination of clients or browsers that are required for that webm flow let us know.  We don't hit a lot of issues with MP4 and H264 or HEVC support that we have today.  We could easily add it, but so far not a ton of demand.

Answer (score 1):

WebM is not supported by Azure Media Services standard encoder. Output file format supported is just limited to MP4 and MPEG2-TS - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-encoder-standard-formats for additional info.